# How to fetch data from asp.net page to an android app without using jsoup?

Tags: asp.net

Currently I have a website of my institute ,I wish to develop an android app for the same to make it easier for the students to access the results which come after filling the details in the URL , For reference you may select the details respectively in the form [Stream- Degree science; Class- F.Y.B.Sc; Division- CPM(A); Roll no- 1743 ] Also, Wanted to know if Json fetching and Parsing Data concept would work for this or not? The answer would be appreciated :)

Tried Jsoup method but that works for only Js websites.

```
try {
    newVersion = Jsoup.connect("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + "com.example.myapp" + "&hl=en")
            .timeout(5000)
            .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
            .referrer("http://www.google.com")
            .get()
            .select("div.hAyfc:nth-child(4) > span:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1)")
            .first()
            .ownText();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Expecting the user to choose login credentials.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to perform screen scraping like Josup then you may try other HTML parsers like [ANTLR4](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/html)

Otherwise, check if your college website has APIs available to perform this operation. Then try to make the API request using POSTMAN and check whether that API is accessible (beware of CORS) and returns data in JSON or any other formats.

If all goes well then you better make the API requests for your app.

**Note: It is recommended to perform an API request instead of screen scraping**